# How do you run JS/jQuery if the domain matches one of two results?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two domains that both go to the exact same website.

[www.bothellhomes.com](http://www.bothellhomes.com) & [www.lookinwa.realgeeks.com](http://www.lookinwa.realgeeks.com)

I want any JS in-between the brackets to run if the domain is either of these sites. Is the below code the right way to do this?

```
if (document.location.href.indexOf('bothellhomes') || ('lookinwa.realgeeks') > -1) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The conditions need to be duplicated, and separate. In addition you should use `window.location.host` as it's less likely to get a false positive due to values in the route:

```
let host = window.location.host;
if (host.indexOf('bothellhomes.com') > -1 || host.indexOf('lookinwa.realgeeks.com') > -1) {
  // do something
}
```

Alternatively you can make the code more extensible by placing the valid domains in an array and checking `indexOf()` on that.

```js
let allowedDomains = ['bothellhomes.com', 'lookinwa.realgeeks.com'];
if (allowedDomains.indexOf(window.location.host) !== -1) {
  // do something
}
```

Note that, depending on your URL routing policy, you may need to add the `www.` prefix to the URLs in the array as well.